# Why is $|x - c| < \delta$ used in epsilon-delta proofs?

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta

**$\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit:**

> **For every** $\varepsilon$ $>$ $0$, **there exists** $\delta$ $>$ $0$ such that **whenever** $0$ $<$ $|x-c|$ $<$ $\delta$, **we have** $|f(x)-L|$ $<$ $\varepsilon$.

My doubt arised from the following source:

> **Prove**, using delta and epsilon, that $\lim_{x \to 5} ( 3x^{2} - 1 ) = 74$

[image: img1]

Feel free to get the bigger picture: refer to "Examples using a Non-Linear Function", highlighted in blue. Note that the picture above it's only part of the proof, which is defining $\varepsilon$

*How To Construct a Delta-Epsilon Proof. (n.d.)*. Milefoot. Retrieved April 27, 2021, from http://www.milefoot.com/math/calculus/limits/DeltaEpsilonProofs03.htm

According to what I'ved learned, we must prove that $0 < |x - c| < \delta$ $\implies$ $0 \leq |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon $, **not** $|x - c| < \delta$ $\implies$ $0 \leq|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon $

Comment: What a horrible explanation you quoted. If you're trying to learn from that source, no wonder you can't do simple ε-δ proofs.

Comment: @user21820 Yes, I eventually realized that. Do you know better sources? I'll soon start working on mathematics again, so I'll need to review.

Comment: Well, Spivak's "Calculus" is a sufficiently rigorous and comprehensive introduction to real analysis. You also need to make sure you know basic FOL (first-order logic), because it is the only way to be able to be 100% sure of yourself in mathematics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given solution makes the assumption that $f$ is continuous at $c$, meaning $L = \lim_{x \to c} f(x) = f(c)$. With this assumption, for $x = c$ we still have $\lvert f(x) - L\rvert < \epsilon$ because $L = f(c)$.

If $f$ is not continuous at $c$, meaning  $L \ne f(c)$, then we could have $f(x)$ is close to $f(c)$ for all $x$ close to but not equal $c$, but at exactly $f(c)$ we have a discontinuity.

Here's a picture from Brilliant.org I've modified (where $x_0 = c$) to include a discontinuity at $f(x_0)$, making $f(x_0)$ totally different from its neighboring values and showing the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition clearly doesn't hold.

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't $|x-c| < \delta$ be applicable for continuous functions **only**?

Comment: @Nameless I assume your question is "what happened to the $\lvert x - c \rvert > 0$ part of the proof. Basically it's not important because it only excludes the trivial case $x = c$.

Comment: @Nameless Agreed. consider $f(x)=1$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$. you need $0<|x|<\delta$ to show that the limit exists at $c=0$, with strict inequality

Comment: Oh I guess you're right for pointwise continuity at the limit.

Comment: I mean that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$, in showing that the limit exists. If instead you changed your definition for the limit of a function to exist to be $$\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x\in\text{dom}(f): 0\leq |x-c|<\delta\Longrightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$ then the limit doesn't exist in this case

Comment: @qwr Yeah, that's my question. I still don't see why it is not important, though. If $x$ makes $f(x)$ undefined, then wouldn't that mean that $\varepsilon$ be undefined? $\varepsilon$ greater than an underterminante form doesn't make sense.

Comment: oh ok I see. there is an implicit assumption in the given solution that f(x) is pointwise continuous. @CSquared you can write an answer and I'll delete this one

Comment: i wouldn't delete this answer. it shows some good thinking and what can go wrong

Comment: sorry for the confusion caused. i added a picture that might be of help. i think of analysis concepts visually so this kind of picture really helped me.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this function:  $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x+2, & x \ne 1 \\ 0, & x = 1, \end{cases}$$ and suppose we are interested in $$L = \lim_{x \to 1} f(x).$$  It is easy to see that we should have $L = 3$.  The epsilon-delta definition says that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $0 < |x - 1| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.  And we can see in this case that we do in fact require $0 < |x-1|$, since if not,  we could choose $\epsilon = 10^{-100}$, and $x = 1$, but $|f(x) - L| = |0 - 1| = 1 > \epsilon$.

The purpose of $\delta$ is to establish a *neighborhood* around the limit point $c$ such that whenever $x$ is within a ball of radius $d$ but is *not equal to* $c$, then the value of the function for all points inside that ball will not deviate from $L$ by more than some chosen $\epsilon$.  So in order to exclude the limit point itself, we can require $0 < |x - c| < \delta$, or we can write something to the effect of "for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $x \ne c$ and $|x - c| < \delta$, then..."  But the effect is the same.

Comment: @Nameless No.  What I'm doing is showing an example of a limit where, if you do **not** require the condition $0 < |x - c|$, then you could choose $x = c$ and violate the epsilon-delta definition despite the fact that the limit **does** exist.  And this is because the function I chose has a *removable discontinuity* at the limit point.

Comment: Thank you for the example. In conclusion, depending on the function, we can either use $|x - c| < \delta$ or $0 < |x - c| < \delta$?

Comment: @Nameless It is simply better to always state $0 < |x - c| < \delta$ in the definition.  There is no case where including the condition $0 < |x - c|$ would lead to an erroneous conclusion regarding the value of the limit.

Comment: But we can still use $|x - c| < \delta$ depending on the function?

Comment: @Nameless How would you know in advance whether you could or could not?  The point of a definition is that it is clear, unambiguous, and universally applicable.  Why would you want to use a definition that only works for *some* functions?

Comment: I'm not talking about modifying the definition, but exploiting the functions properties to devise quicker methods to prove. For example, continuity of a function would allow us to let $x = c$, consequently, we can use $|x -  c| < \delta$ instead of $0 < |x -  c| < \delta$ . Therefore, we can convert the former to $-\delta < x - c < \delta$

Comment: @Nameless regardless of whether or not $|x-c|<\delta$ or $0<|x-c|<\delta$, the inequality $-\delta<x-c<\delta$ still holds. The inequality $|a|\leq b$ iff $-b\leq a\leq b$ holds even if $a=0$.

Comment: @CSquared Yes, it holds because it was derived from $|x - c| < \delta$ even if $x = c$, right? We can also say $c - \delta < x < c + \delta$.

Answer (score 1):

**Definition:**

> Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be non-empty and suppose $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function. For $a,L\in\mathbb{R}$, we say that $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=L$ if and only if $$\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x\in A:0<|x-a|<\delta\Longrightarrow |f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$$
> Note that $a$ need not be in $A$ and/or $f$ need not be defined at $a$.

**Examples:**

1. Say $A=(-1,0)\cup (0,1)$ and $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in A$. Then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$, but $0\not\in A$.
2. Say $A=\mathbb{R}$ and $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is $f(x)=1$ for $x\neq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$. Then $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=1$.

**Definition:**

> Let $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be non-empty and suppose $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function. For $a\in A$, we say that $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$, i.e,
> $$\forall\varepsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x\in A:0<|x-a|<\delta\Longrightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$$

Note that Example 2. shows that the limit of a function can exist at a point, but the function need not be continuous, or even defined at that point.

In the definition of continuity at a point, the second definition, we must have $a\in A$ for this definition to make sense, otherwise $|f(x)-f(a)|$ is meaningless, as in Example 1. In the case where $|x-a|=0$ i.e., $x=a$, everything is fine, since the function $f$ must be defined on all of $A$, so $|f(x)-f(a)|=|f(a)-f(a)|=0$, so we can loosen our definition of continuity to allow for $|x-a|=0$, since the function is defined at that point.

The answer by heropup and the comments under qwr's answer show examples of what happen if you alter the definition of a limit to exsit at a point.

Comment: I don't see how, in your example 2, intuitively speaking, $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 1$ if $f(x) = 0$  when $x = 0$.

Comment: @Nameless have you tried drawing a picture?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it. I think, computationally, we can directly substitute $x$ in $f(x)$ with 0 as follows: $\lim_{x \to 0} f(0) = 0$ We defined $f(x) =0$ when $x = 0$, right?

Comment: @Nameless no. you can only do that if you know before hand that the function is continuous at $0$. in this case, the function is not continuous at $0$, so your method is not valid

Comment: @Nameless regarding example two, if $\varepsilon>0$, then choose $\delta=\varepsilon$. For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $0<|x-0|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-1|=|1-1|=0<\delta=\varepsilon$ so $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=1\neq f(0)=0$.